# Python :How to generate a power law graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph-theory, networkx

I have installed networkx and matplotlib packages. How can I generate a power law graph based on degree correlation i.e. graphs with high or low degree of homophily

Answer (score 0):

[`networkx.generators.barabasi_albert_graph`](http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/generated/networkx.generators.random_graphs.barabasi_albert_graph.html) will generate a graph according to the [Barabasi-Albert model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barab%C3%A1si%E2%80%93Albert_model), which will have a power-law degree distribution.